# How do I give credit to the authors of Wikipedia text?

Tags: wikipedia, copyright-display

I'm working on an MVC project where most of the text of the pages will be extracted from Wikipedia (possibly, but not necessarily English), and manually translated in additional languages. As far as I can see, credit to the authors is required, as stated here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License

My question is, how do I create attribution text/links to add to my pages? Will I have to manually find out all the authors on each and every Wikipedia source page? Is there any credit template/builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A link to the article is sufficient attribution (see [the terms of use](https://foundation.wikimedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use/en#7._Licensing_of_Content)), except for images, which do not have a unified license and so there's no easy way to give attribution. The media viewer GUI has a license template, but you cannot invoke that programmatically.

Comment: Thanks @Tgr. So, 7. Licensing of Content, g. Re-use, states:
"Through hyperlink (where possible) or URL to the page or pages that you are re-using (since each page has a history page that lists all authors and editors)"

I'm thinking to go with the following:
1) Get the parts of the text of the Wikipedia page that I want to re-use, edit them, and translate them in the additional laguages;
2) Add a "Source(s)" list below each text in my project (or in the page footer), with the links to the original Wikipedia pages where I extracted the text from.

Do you think it would be ok this way?

Comment: Yeah, that's okay and the common way of attributing Wikipedia content.

Comment: All done. As I'm using multiple Wikipedia pages as sources, one for each language, and I'm merging all the languages in a single translated text, I've added this info and link below each edited text in my project: `Source: Wikipedia (English | Italiano) - Edited`. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WIKI:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties

There is a query you can access to get contributors:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Reddit&prop=contributors

Comment: Thanks @Welyngton, will have a look.